# Chat room is frozen?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

[Gavin Simpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429846/gavin-simpson) mentioned to me that he gets the following when trying to post in the "Ten Fold" chat room:

> I see "This room is frozen; new
>   messages cannot be added." where the
>   message box would be.

I don't see this (presumably since I'm an admin).  The site chat room should not be frozen, regardless of how active it is.  Can this be fixed?

Comment: Note: I "unfroze" the chat room myself, but I still don't think that this should be happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the `/faq` for the rules, specifically

http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.
>
> Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. **Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen.** Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.

Relevant bit bolded.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  I understand this rule for random rooms created for specific topics, but don't you think that you should keep rooms associated with specific sites unfrozen regardless of activity?  You never know when people may eventually start using it, and freezing it simply prevents that possibility.

Comment: @shane that's a good point; maybe we should preserve (prevent from freezing) the last site-specific room that exists on stackexchange.com?

Comment: IMO, each site should have a chat room, and those rooms should never be frozen; if that means the last site-specific room on SE, then yes.  Otherwise, you can just automatically create a chat room when a new site is created, and that would be the permanent room.  These chat rooms are great, and provide a really nice way for communities to communicate outside the normal channels.

Comment: I'd like to second Shane's suggestion for site-specific chat rooms. For rooms with a more academic-flavour there will inevitably be periods with low or no traffic due to the annual natural of grant applications and 'fieldwork' etc.